# Retrive xml attributes using SaxParser with certain constraint

Tags: java, xml, parsing, saxparser

I have some xml file that looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1">
    <xmi:Documentation exporter="StarUML" exporterVersion="2.0"/>
    <uml:Model xmi:id="AAAAAAFareTxvby24dA=" xmi:type="uml:Model" name="RootModel">
        <packagedElement xmi:id="AAAAAAFF+qBWK6M3Z8Y=" name="Model" visibility="public" xmi:type="uml:Model">
            <packagedElement xmi:id="AAAAAAFardVTNLu3sj8=" name="Collaboration1" visibility="public" isAbstract="false" isFinalSpecialization="false" isLeaf="false" xmi:type="uml:Collaboration">
                <ownedMember xmi:id="AAAAAAFardVTNLu4D8A=" name="Interaction1" visibility="public" isReentrant="true" xmi:type="uml:Interaction">
                    <lifeline xmi:id="AAAAAAFarde+1LvKN6g=" name="Lifeline1" visibility="public" xmi:type="uml:Lifeline" represents="AAAAAAFarde+1LvJ564="/>
                    <lifeline xmi:id="AAAAAAFardf7yrvsb8c=" name="MenuUI" visibility="public" xmi:type="uml:Lifeline" represents="AAAAAAFardf7yrvrcg8=">
                        <xmi:Extension extender="StarUML">
                            <stereotype value="boundary"/>
                        </xmi:Extension>
                    </lifeline>
                    <lifeline xmi:id="AAAAAAFardxJILwRIg4=" name="Lifeline2" visibility="public" xmi:type="uml:Lifeline" represents="AAAAAAFardxJILwQ1Co=">
                        <xmi:Extension extender="StarUML">
                            <stereotype value="Control"/>
                        </xmi:Extension>
                    </lifeline>
                    <lifeline xmi:id="AAAAAAFard3TVLwzblk=" name="JASP Database" visibility="public" xmi:type="uml:Lifeline" represents="AAAAAAFard3TVLwyteg=">
                        <xmi:Extension extender="StarUML">
                            <stereotype value="entity"/>
                        </xmi:Extension>
                    </lifeline>
                    <message xmi:id="AAAAAAFareGVNLxXGek=" name="showJASPForm" visibility="public" xmi:type="uml:Message" messageSort="synchCall" messageKind="complete" receiveEvent="AAAAAAFareTxvby4sh8=" sendEvent="AAAAAAFareTxvby3aMk="/>
                    <message xmi:id="AAAAAAFareJipLxuCJI=" name="CreateForm" visibility="public" xmi:type="uml:Message" messageSort="synchCall" messageKind="complete" receiveEvent="AAAAAAFareTxvby6G+A=" sendEvent="AAAAAAFareTxvby5M/Y="/>
                    <message xmi:id="AAAAAAFareMNVryH/kg=" name="InsertForm" visibility="public" xmi:type="uml:Message" messageSort="synchCall" messageKind="complete" receiveEvent="AAAAAAFareTxvby89AI=" sendEvent="AAAAAAFareTxvby7vl0="/>
                    <message xmi:id="AAAAAAFareM+ArydC68=" name="ShowSucces" visibility="public" xmi:type="uml:Message" messageSort="reply" messageKind="complete" receiveEvent="AAAAAAFareTxvby+fr4=" sendEvent="AAAAAAFareTxvby9N9U="/>
                    <fragment xmi:id="AAAAAAFareTxvby3aMk=" xmi:type="uml:OccurrenceSpecification" covered="AAAAAAFarde+1LvKN6g="/>
                    <fragment xmi:id="AAAAAAFareTxvby4sh8=" xmi:type="uml:OccurrenceSpecification" covered="AAAAAAFardf7yrvsb8c="/>
                    <fragment xmi:id="AAAAAAFareTxvby5M/Y=" xmi:type="uml:OccurrenceSpecification" covered="AAAAAAFardf7yrvsb8c="/>
                    <fragment xmi:id="AAAAAAFareTxvby6G+A=" xmi:type="uml:OccurrenceSpecification" covered="AAAAAAFardxJILwRIg4="/>
                    <fragment xmi:id="AAAAAAFareTxvby7vl0=" xmi:type="uml:OccurrenceSpecification" covered="AAAAAAFardxJILwRIg4="/>
                    <fragment xmi:id="AAAAAAFareTxvby89AI=" xmi:type="uml:OccurrenceSpecification" covered="AAAAAAFard3TVLwzblk="/>
                    <fragment xmi:id="AAAAAAFareTxvby9N9U=" xmi:type="uml:OccurrenceSpecification" covered="AAAAAAFard3TVLwzblk="/>
                    <fragment xmi:id="AAAAAAFareTxvby+fr4=" xmi:type="uml:OccurrenceSpecification" covered="AAAAAAFarde+1LvKN6g="/>
                </ownedMember>
                <ownedAttribute xmi:id="AAAAAAFarde+1LvJ564=" name="Role1" visibility="public" isStatic="false" isLeaf="false" type="AAAAAAFardeb5LvGhG0=" isReadOnly="false" isOrdered="false" isUnique="false" xmi:type="uml:Property" aggregation="none" isDerived="false" isID="false"/>
                <ownedAttribute xmi:id="AAAAAAFardf7yrvrcg8=" name="Role2" visibility="public" isStatic="false" isLeaf="false" isReadOnly="false" isOrdered="false" isUnique="false" xmi:type="uml:Property" aggregation="none" isDerived="false" isID="false"/>
                <ownedAttribute xmi:id="AAAAAAFardxJILwQ1Co=" name="Role3" visibility="public" isStatic="false" isLeaf="false" isReadOnly="false" isOrdered="false" isUnique="false" xmi:type="uml:Property" aggregation="none" isDerived="false" isID="false"/>
                <ownedAttribute xmi:id="AAAAAAFard3TVLwyteg=" name="Role4" visibility="public" isStatic="false" isLeaf="false" isReadOnly="false" isOrdered="false" isUnique="false" xmi:type="uml:Property" aggregation="none" isDerived="false" isID="false"/>
            </packagedElement>
            <packagedElement xmi:id="AAAAAAFardeb5LvGhG0=" name="Actor1" visibility="public" isAbstract="false" isFinalSpecialization="false" isLeaf="false" xmi:type="uml:Actor"/>
        </packagedElement>
    </uml:Model>
</xmi:XMI>
```

How can I retrieve this xml using `SaxParser` with certain constraint like: I want to retrieve attribute **"name: "** in message elements, but with constraint that message must have `messageSort="synchCall"`.

I've already created the code for getting names in lifeline and message elements with `SaxParser`:

```
qLength = qName.length();
for (int i = 0; i < qLength; i++) {
    String qValuename = qName.toString().toLowerCase();

    if (qValuename.equalsIgnoreCase("lifeline")) {
        length = attributes.getLength();
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            String attrName = attributes.getLocalName(j);
            if (attrName.compareToIgnoreCase("name") == 0) {
                String val = attributes.getValue(j);
                System.out.println("FunctionsName: " + val);
            }
        }
    } else if (qValuename.equalsIgnoreCase("message")) {
        length = attributes.getLength();
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            String attrName = attributes.getLocalName(j);
            if (attrName.compareToIgnoreCase("name") == 0) {
                String val = attributes.getValue(j);
                System.out.println("Message: " + val);
            }
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

But I need to be more specific when I want to retrieve name in message with constraint : `messageSort="synchCall".`

Comment: check out XPath and its implementations for Java or XML streaming API.

Comment: is it really necessary to change the parser ? is it really hard to retrive specific attributes in SaxParser with certain constraint sir ? 
thans for your respon kind sir @khachik

Comment: it is not "very" hard, you just need to implement manually as per in the code you posted.

Comment: hello sir, im open to anything else